# Expand x axis when x is a string (make xlim wider)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following pandas data frame:

```py
print(so)
       Time  Minions  Crime_rate
0   2018-01     1907    0.147352
1   2018-02     2094    0.165234
2   2018-03     2227    0.148181
3   2018-04     2101    0.135174
4   2018-05     2321    0.132271
5   2018-06     2208    0.128623
6   2018-07     2593    0.140378
7   2018-08     2660    0.145865
8   2018-09     2488    0.149920
9   2018-10     2640    0.152273
10  2018-11     2501    0.138345
11  2018-12     2379    0.134931
```

I want to plot `Time` on the x axis, `Minions` on the y axis and `Crime_rate` on a secondary y axis. **The problem is that the x axis is cropped and I want to expand it.** I tried the following code:

```py
so.plot(x="Time", y="Minions", kind="bar", color="orange", legend=False)
plt.ylabel("Number of Minions")
so["Crime_rate"].plot(secondary_y=True, rot=90)
plt.ylabel("Minion crime rate")
plt.ylim(0, 1)
# plt.xlim(min, max)
plt.show()
```

The code returns the following plot:
[image: PLOT]

I had done this before using `plt.xlim()`, but `so["Time"]` is a string, so I cannot subtract or add to the limits. How can I expand the x axis limits to show the first and last bars?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a solution that involves keeping the x axis as a string. To solve this, I had to avoid setting the x axis and then overwriting its values using `set_xticklabels()`.

```py
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1 = so["Minions"].plot(ax=ax1, kind="bar", color="orange", legend=False)
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
so["Crime_rate"].plot(ax=ax2, legend=False)
ax1.set_ylabel("Minions")
ax1.set_xlabel("Time")
ax2.set_ylabel("Minion crime rate")
ax2.set_xlim(-0.5, len(so) - 0.5) # extend the x axis by 0.5 to the left and 0.5 to the right
ax2.set_ylim(0, 1)
ax2.set_xticklabels(so["Time"])
plt.show()
```

[image: FIX]

This works because I never set the x axis in `ax1`, so it was generically set to a `[0, 1, 2, ..., 10, 11]`. This way, I could set the x axis range from `-0.5` to `11.5`.

Comment: look into `ax.margins`

Comment: Can you state where to place this argument? Is an entirely different solution to this one?

Comment: `ax.margins` could replace the `ax2.set_xlim` call; but I'm not actually sure if that would work with pandas plots.